# Pylab - use plot() result as image directly

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I create plot with pylab plot() function, I can show it, or plot it. Could I also access is as the matrix of pixels?

I would like to avoid operations like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

plt.savefig("name.png")
mpimg.imread("name.png")
```

Is there a way how to get image matrix directly from created plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the methods you mention can work with a "file-like" object, so there's no need to write a file to disk:

```
import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
plt.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
imgdata.seek(0)
mpimg.imread(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use `numpy.fromstring` and export the fig as a bytestring.

I found the exact solution to your problem [here](http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/drupal/node/1141).

```
def fig2data ( fig ):
    """
    @brief Convert a Matplotlib figure to a 4D numpy array with RGBA channels and return it
    @param fig a matplotlib figure
    @return a numpy 3D array of RGBA values
    """
    # draw the renderer
    fig.canvas.draw ( )

    # Get the RGBA buffer from the figure
    w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    buf = numpy.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8 )
    buf.shape = ( w, h,4 )

    # canvas.tostring_argb give pixmap in ARGB mode. Roll the ALPHA channel to have it in RGBA mode
    buf = numpy.roll ( buf, 3, axis = 2 )
    return buf
```